# How can we navigate back to previous view programmatically in iPhone?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am working on iPhone application which based on navigation controller. for example there are 2 views here.

A (UITableViewController) and B (ViewController)

the quest is here. when user select an item in View A. The application will force navigation controller to hide navigation bar before push View B to be showed, like the statement below:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controllerB animated:TRUE];
```

That is, View B is there. but How can available user to navigate back to View A without navigation bar? In this case, we will use a button 'back' to let user tap on it to navigate back to View A. Could you help me?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can call the popViewControllerAnimated method:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift Version

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
 _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

From this post: [Xcode 8 / Swift 3: "Expression of type UIViewController? is unused" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843049/xcode-8-swift-3-expression-of-type-uiviewcontroller-is-unused-warning)