# popViewController Thread 1 SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Currently playing around with my a viewcontroller. So the thing is, instead of me having the controls in the top, I want to make my own custom previous button. 
I figured that the below code is what i should use:

```
@IBAction func previousButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

It makes an error, `Expression of type 'UIViewController?' is unused.`

I went ahead and figured that I could use _ = before self. However I get a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.`
So really, I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: do you actually have a navigation controller?

Comment: Yes i do, actually i followed this tutorial: 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQjH5qHwU6Y&list=PLoN_ejT35AEgP1y2tkOTYOKOFHXUBkH2z&index=3 

You can skip to around 8 minutes

Comment: I think that tutorial is not in Swift 3, that's why you're getting that warning on the first place: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843049/xcode-8-swift-3-expression-of-type-uiviewcontroller-is-unused-warning

Comment: thats the exact post i read, which made me use _ =, but i still get a SIGABRT error

Comment: have you tried this: 

if self.navigationController != nil {
  self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
}

Comment: yea, still get the SIGABRT

Comment: what does the call stack show when you get this error?

Comment: check if you connected the outlets/actions correctly in your storyboard

Comment: 0x1079b5f34 <+159>: movq   0xe81325(%rip), %rbx      ; (void *)0x00000001074f9d20: objc_release 

Don't know if this tells anything?

Doublechecked my connections in the storyboard, and they are fine, no doubles

Comment: the call stack is what's showing in the left-side panel, when you get this crash. It basically shows every method that was executing prior to the crash.

Comment: I have no idea what i should benefit from this call stack, its just a bunch of numbers.

Comment: well, that thing is for a reason there, for people to look and see if the methods they expect to be called were called as well as going step by step backwards checking if all the values they expect to be passing are passing correctly. In your case, something is definitely wrong.

Comment: have you tried to place a breakpoint inside of the previousButtonTapped method and see the values of the objects there, if everything is not nil ?

Comment: my gosh, this is embarresing.. 1st day with xCode i must say though.. But i found the method that conflicted after all, and you are right, by some reason my outlet was wrong.. I just deleted it, and made the connection again. - now it works!

Comment: ;) you see...extra pair of eyes is always good

Comment: Appreciate it mate! :-)