# Swift 3 how to dismiss UIViewController after UIAlertController action

Tags: swift3, uialertcontroller

I have an alert controller and want to close the view controller after pressing OK but can't figure out how. `self.dismiss(animated: true)` only closes the alert controller itself. Here is my code.

```
let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password updatd", message: "Your password has been changed successfully", preferredStyle: .alert)

let okAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action -> Void in }

alertController.addAction(okAction)

self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I tried this which only removed the current view controller but not back to the root view controller.

```
let okAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action -> Void in
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)}
```

This gave me a warning `expression of type UIViewController is unused`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigation Controller:

Previous Controller

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Root Controller

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Modal View Controller:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I don't have a storyboard.

Comment: Ok, then you are using Xib's?

Comment: How do you present another ViewController? I'm not really advanced in programmatically creating everything but I would like to learn

Comment: See my Edit Above

Comment: Try this as well for the most recent error you received http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843049/xcode-8-swift-3-expression-of-type-uiviewcontroller-is-unused-warning